# How to know if some sprite is running any action in cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Is there any way to know if some sprite is running any action or not in cocos2d?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check number of running actions of your sprite, for example

```
CCSprite* sprite = [// something here];
int actionsCount = [sprite numberOfRunningActions];
```